# "Straight up and down" meaning

Tags: grammar, adverbs

A dictionary defines the word **vertical** *adj* as: **straight up and down.**

So can I say someone **draw a line that is straight up and down?**

Can the word **horizontal** mean **straight from side to side?**

Please explain.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

> Vertical

is from top to bottom or bottom to top, i.e.
[image: Vertical Line]

> Horizontal

is from left to right or right to left, i.e.

[image: Horizontal Line]

Comment: I am familiar with that but my question is different.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can say "draw a line that is straight up and down", and the person should draw a vertical line.  Similarly I would understand "straight (from) side to side" to mean horizontal.